# Rematch/Reducers- Error writing the test cases

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to write unit test cases for my reducers.js using React Testing Library.I am getting some error which i am not able to figure out. Can someone help me understand where i am going wrong?

reducers.js-

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  userData: {},
};

const setUserData = (state, { key, value }) => ({ // {key: value}
  ...state,
  userData: {
    ...state.userData,
    [key]: value,
  },
});
```

reducers.test.js

```
import reducersDefault from './reducers';

const {
  setUserData,
} = reducersDefault.reducers;

describe('reducers', () => {
  it('setUserData', () => expect(setUserData({}, { key: { name: 'test' } })).toEqual({
    userData: { userData: { key: { name: 'test' } } },
  }));
});
```

With the above code, i am getting the below error-

```
Expected value to equal:
      {"userData": {"userData": {"key": {"name": "test"}}}}
    Received:
      {"userData": {"undefined": undefined}}
```

Trying to figure out what i am doing wrong here. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You test fails because your function doesn't work properly. You cannot destructure an object to key/value - what you are doing currently extracts the values of `key` and `value` properties of the object you are passing there.

Here's a better approach:

```
const setUserData = (state, data) => ({
  ...state,
  userData: {
    ...state.userData,
    ..data, // put every property inside data to userData
  },
});
```

LE: After reading your comment I realised you are calling your function wrong in the test:

```
expect(setUserData({}, { key: 'name', value: 'test' })).toEqual({
    userData: { name: 'test' }
}));
```

This should work as you expect (without changing setUserData).

Comment: Yes, i am extracting key and value of the object on purpose as i have some requirement to cache the response for each input key. So can you suggest a way to achieve this for the given method?

Comment: You should extract each key from data using Object.keys(data). How are you calling setUserData usually?

Comment: In. my effects, i am calling setUserData like this.setUserData({ key: userDataInputParams, value: userDataResponse });

Comment: My functionality works fine with this approach, but i am facing issues writing test cases now with the given way :(

Comment: What to put in toEqual?

Comment: {
    userData: { userData: { name: 'test' } } } edited again now that you mention it :)

Comment: It throws me error- with expected format as {"userData": {"userData": {"key": "name"}}} and Received {"userData": {"name": "test"}}

Comment: Yeah, we had an extra userData there. Edited now